# Microsoft Graph Drives Filter doesn't apply

Tags: filter, microsoft-graph-api, odata, filtering, microsoft-graph-files

I try to get SharePoint library by name using Micrsoft Graph.

Following query return names of two libraries (drives, to be more precise):
**https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/SiteID/drives?$select=name,id**

Result:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives(name,id)",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "b!AzzEy..............MAZI5",
            "name": "Dokumenty"
        },
        {
            "id": "b!AzzEy.............B-G2yh",
            "name": "serwis"
        }
    ]
}
```

To return only one by name, I do such $filter

**https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/SiteID/drives?$select=name,id&$filter=name eq 'serwis'**

but it doesn't work - it return all drives.

Where is problem in URL?

Comment: 2 years later, $filter still only validated and then ignored on the drives endpoint, and to really show how much they care, they deleted the suggestion too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the $filter does not work against the Drives endpoint.Please feel free to upvote the feature ask here - https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/41172841-microsoft-graph-api-odata-support-to-fetch-dri

Comment: Thank you for your reply; I already doubted my understanding of filters. 
Of course, I cast my vote. Thanks again.